# Keep incoming call going on while navigating between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

We have implemented the twilio incoming call feature with in our aps.net MVC app where the users on the application can answer the incoming calls from the browser, the implementation is working good but now we are facing an issue, as the application is built using mvc, when the user navigates on the application from the current screen to some other screen the call got disconnected.

What we want to achieve is that once the user is on call he can continue the call and can navigate with in the app to other pages without the call disconnecting. we are already looked into a couple of other options like iFrame or opening a new window but they are not what we want to do, Will there be any other method which we can use to achieve the required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a task which is scheduled, I've use Hangfire for this, it will allow background jobs to execute while the UI can move between pages.

look at the following URL for more information on how to use the library

https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: It is not like we want the background scheduling, but what we want is the call to continue while the users navigate in different pages in the application. We are already using the SignalR for pushing the call notifications but the issue is to keep a connection alive while navigating.

Comment: With hangfire you can execute immediately, it's great for executing queries for fire and forget. You can execute the call and keep the UI responsive, the UI can navigate to another page, or the user can even close the browser. Take a look at the package and see if it fits your needs, so far in what you're describing it does.